# How to fix SqlException: Invalid column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using EF code first migrations in MVC5 with SQL Server.
I created a post method, I'm posting DTO data from the client and its all fine i believe, but when i try to save the data to the db i get this invalid column name exception on a foreign key property.

This is the first time i actually counter this error. I checked other questions and most answers were related to the [ForeignKey] data annotation but i think i implemented it the right way

This is the Model

```
public class ServiceProvider
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public double YearsOfExperiance { get; set; }
        public double AverageRank { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public ICollection<JobImage> JobImages { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public bool Approved { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller ActionResult method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddServiceProvider(ServiceProviderDTO serviceProvider)
        {
            bool isInDb = _context.ServiceProviders.Any(s => s.Name == serviceProvider.Name) ? true : false;
            //var serviceProviderInDb = _context.ServiceProviders.Where(s => s.Name == serviceProvider.Name).FirstOrDefault();

            var newServiceProvider = new ServiceProvider();

            if (isInDb == false)
            {
                newServiceProvider = new ServiceProvider
                {
                    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    Name = serviceProvider.Name,
                    PhoneNumber = serviceProvider.PhoneNumber,
                    YearsOfExperiance = serviceProvider.YearsOfExperiance,
                    Nationality = serviceProvider.Nationality,
                    CategoryId = serviceProvider.CategoryId,
                    Active = true,
                    Approved = serviceProvider.Approved == null ? false : serviceProvider.Approved.Value
                };

                _context.ServiceProviders.Add(newServiceProvider);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

The error occurs on `_context.SaveChanges();` 
It states that `CategoryId` is an invalid column name

This is not the first time that i use code first migrations and i never came across this error before so i really have no idea why this happens!

Comment: So......what's the model for the `Category` table?  Is it's PK just `Id` or is it in fact `CategoryId`?

Comment: Have you changed the column name recently?

Comment: @BrendanGreen its just Id

Comment: @tymtam nope not really

Comment: What does `not really` mean?

Comment: Can you please go to Management Studio and have it generate / extract the `CREATE TABLE` scripts for the `Category` table and also for the `ServiceProvider` table (and include both in the question).

Comment: Have you tried marking the `Category` as `virtual` (e.g. `public virtual Category Category { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

I would have the model like this.

The `ForeignKey` attribute belong to the `Category` property

```
public class ServiceProvider
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public double YearsOfExperiance { get; set; }
        public double AverageRank { get; set; }
        public string Nationality { get; set; }
        public ICollection<JobImage> JobImages { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }    
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public bool Approved { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: there may be other issues you have...do you have the option of staring from a clean db and re-running the migrations?

Comment: `'didn't work` is not much help - please describe exceptions etc

Comment: Well, the problem started when i ran update-database on a new one. i was running the db on the local visual studio db then i ran all the migrations on a sql server one

Answer (score 0):

you need delete this property `public int CategoryId { get; set; }`

your property `public Category Category { get; set; }` is the ForeignKey and add the DataAnnotations `[ForeignKey("CategoryId")]`

it would look like this

```
public class ServiceProvider
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public double YearsOfExperiance { get; set; }
    public double AverageRank { get; set; }
    public string Nationality { get; set; }
    public ICollection<JobImage> JobImages { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Rank> Ranks { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }

    public bool Approved { get; set; }
}
```